# Rails - how to get find domain url in a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had `request.env['http_host']` working on localhost, but it causes an error when referenced in a layout page on heroku.

This request works in a view and displays the correct base url, but it causes an error when I move the code to the layout.  Note - I'm using this to build absolute urls for images in html emails.

```
  <%= "#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}/assets/email_header_image.png" %> 
  <%= image_tag "#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}/assets/email_header_image.png" %>
```

error received:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: A potential way to get around this is to set global settings for dev vs prod.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the host without the port, just use:

```
request.host
```

edit: Oops, I've just noticed that you're using the code in the view. I don't know if it is visible over there, I've only used it in controllers, but that's fairly simple to overcome by setting an instance variable.

Comment: `request` should be present in the view as well, as it was in the example given.

Answer (score 5):

1. In your controller, set an instance variable equal to the host:

   - `@host = request.host`
2. In your view, reference the instance variable using

   - `<%= @host %>`